# Identify processes running more than 3 hrs in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I want to find out processes running more than 3 hrs, I have written a command for this but it's not returning expected output

```
ps -u <user> -o pid,stime,pcpu,pmem,etime,cmd --sort=start_time | \
    grep <searchString> | grep -v grep| awk '{print $5}' | \
        sed 's/:|-/ /g;'| awk '{print $4" "$3" "$2" "$1"}' | \
            awk '$1+$2*60+$3*3600+$4*86400 > 10800'
```

but it's printing the values of etime in output. But expected output is, command should print the values of  "pid,stime,pcpu,pmem,etime,cmd"

I am not able to find exact issue with this.

Comment: The problem in your script comes from [stime in procps-ng](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/master/ps/output.c#L1017) which has different formats for different timestamps, don't use it if you need to parse it later. Also [etime in procps-ng](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/master/ps/output.c#L482) has 3 available formats, use it with caution too. These columns have strange formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to find running process for more than 3 hrs with below command.

```
ps -u <user> -o pid,stime,pcpu,pmem,etime,cmd --sort=start_time |grep -v grep|awk 'substr($0,23,2) > 3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are executing "awk '{print $5}'" which is taking in the input and printing out only column 5 which in your case is "etime" , everything from this point on is lost.

If your system supports etimes (notice the s on the end), you can easily do this with

```
ps -eo pid,etimes,etime,comm,user,tty | awk '{if ( $2>10800) print $0}'
```

on a system not supporting etimes which has a standard output of etime which hh:mm:ss or just mm:ss if no hours have passed

```
ps -eo pid,etime,comm,user,tty | awk '{seconds_old=10800 ; split($2,a,":",sep)  ; if(length(a) < 3)  b = (a[1] *60) + (a[2]) ; else  b=((a[1]*3600) + (a[2] *60) + (a[3])) ; if(b > seconds_old ) print $0}'
```

Adjust "seconds_old" to change the age you want to test for:

There are various other methods of doing this using Find for example:
explained here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/181477/how-do-i-kill-processes-older-than-t

However, the solution should match your expected output

Comment: etimes is not supported by system, hence converting it into seconds and then checking

Comment: i will update with a soltuion for systems without etimes

Comment: can you please help me to modify above command to handle format "2-02:03:12"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`ps -u <user> -o pid,stime,pcpu,pmem,etime=,cmd --sort=start_time|grep <searchString>|while read z;do tago=$(echo $z|awk '{print $5}'|sed -E 's/(:|-)/ /g'| awk '{print $4+$3*60+$2*3600+$1*86400}');if [ $tago -ge 10800 ];then echo $z;fi;done`

It prints only processes `>= 10800` secs old.
You can readjust the output further to fit your needs.

Comment: Its not working... it still printing all the processes which are running less than 3 hrs

Comment: What Distro/OS are you running it on?